# Why did my content disappear in Umbraco's Editor?

Tags: umbraco

I have a Website Project using Umbraco 7. The content of a page that I can clearly see on the front end is not binding to the fields when I try to edit in Umbraco's back end. Instead all the data type fields are left at their default state. If I try to Publish a page, all my content on that page is reset to nothing.

I wish I had more to go on, but this problem just seemed to "happen". Some actions I took before the issue: deleted the .suo file, deleted the app_data/temp/clientdependancy folder, added whole project to TFS source control, and attempted to publish site to remote server.

Comment: Try to republish whole site.
Does application have right permissions to files ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content displayed on the front end is cached - first in a file called App_data/Umbraco.config (which is read from disk and held in memory), and if that isn't there it is re-created from the DB. The problem you're seeing is probably some corruption of your content held in the database, which when you try to publish overwrites what you hold in this cached file, which then makes the page disappear.

It can be caused by a number of things - you changing data types, data type corruption, document type corruption. There are a few things you can try

- Try and roll your page content back to a previous version. You can do this in the umbraco UI
- Try and re-create the page (if your site does not have too much content)
- Check for any entries in the ASP.net event log in IIS, or in the UmbracoLog database table on your db which point to an error
- Try and copy the page within Umbraco to another location or another site within the same installation to see if the content is restored.

Other than that, without a specific error it's quite difficult to diagnose the issue, but try those things and feed back. Good luck